# Using nav host fragment and bottom navigation view inside fragment?

Tags: android, navigationcontroller, android-navigationview, android-navigation-graph, android-bottomnavigationview

I have nav host fragment and bottom navigation view inside home fragment as below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="home.HomeFragment2">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/homeNavHost"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomMenu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/staging_menu_navigation1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The menu as

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/staging_dashboard_nav_graph"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/menu_dashboard" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/staging_offer_nav_graph"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_offer"
    android:title="@string/menu_offers" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/staging_profile_nav_graph"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
    android:title="@string/menu_profile" />
</menu>
```

The navigation graph as

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_menu_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment3">

<include app:graph="@navigation/staging_dashboard_nav_graph" />
<include app:graph="@navigation/staging_offer_nav_graph" />
<include app:graph="@navigation/staging_profile_nav_graph" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment3"
    android:name="com.octave.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="DashboardFragment" />

</navigation>
```

The other graphs are as

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_dashboard_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="dashboard_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/dashboard_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

Offer graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_offer_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/offersFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/offersFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.offers.OffersFragment"
    android:label="offers_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/offers_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

Profile graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_profile_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/profileFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="profile_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment" />
```

In my home fragment I am setting up as

```
binding.bottomMenu.setupWithNavController(Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.homeNavHost))
```

When I tap on bottom menu items the fragment doesn't change.
What is wrong over here?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to create another nav graph with the bottom navigation bar that is already a part of the default nav graph, you first need to change the `defaultNavHost` value to false in XML of wherever your nav host fragment is in. then find `NavHost` to get `NavController`:

```
val navHost = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.${yourNavHostFragment} as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHost.navController
view.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView).setupWithNavController(navController!!)
```